# Google Doc Query works in one sheet, but gives a parsing error in another sheet

Tags: google-docs

I have a google doc query that works in one spreadsheet. But when I duplicate the spreadsheet the query does not work and I receive a parsing error: `Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMNCol2`.

My query is as follows:

```
=QUERY(importRange("sheetID‬", "Transactions!A1:Z200"), "select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 where Col2='Room Booking'")
```

I tried changing the query to:

```
=QUERY(importRange("sheetID‬", "Transactions!A1:Z200"), "select A, B, C, D where B='Room Booking'")
```

but receive the error: `Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMNA`

Thank you for any input on what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for that! Also, () I was unaware that there was a New and Old version of Google Spreadsheets. The formula worked in my old sheets, but not in the new sheets. (After some luck in finding this out) . . . the New version requires IMPORTRANGE to be "Connected" to the sheet before it will actually import the data.

Answer (score 1):

In the new Google Sheets, IMPORTRANGE requires the whole URL as spreadsheet_key.